# How do I add extra data to model before submit from form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a form that a user fills out that I need to add some extra 'behind the scenes' data to before creating the object in my DB.  For instance, data like a `referrer_url, clout_score` etc.  How do I go about doing it?  Are the methods something that should sit in the Controller or the Model?

For instance, I need to be able to add what the method `create_url` returns to the :

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "You've been added to the waiting list!"
        render 'show'
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :use_type)
    end

    def create_url
     url = SecureRandom.hex(4)
    end
```

end

**User Table in DB**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.integer :init_spot
      t.integer :current_spot
      t.string :referrer_url
      t.integer :clout

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Should I just do an `@user.update_attributes` in the same controller action and call my methods that way? Like:

```
if @user.save
      @user.update_attributes(referrer_url: create_url, clout: calc_clout, etc.)
      flash[:success] .....
      render 'new'
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "extra?" Is this data that needs to be sent to the model which does not correspond to a field in the model?

Comment: @MarsAtomic there are other fields in the Model that I need to put data in.  I don't want to hide the parameters in the form since they could be tampered with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the hash options of the [`ActiveRecord::Core#new`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-c-new) method in your controller:

```
@user = User.new(user_params.merge(referrer_url: create_url))
```

Or move all that into a separate method for a clearer and more readable code:

```
@user = User.new(user_params_with_additional_data)

private

def user_params_with_additional_data
  user_params.merge(referrer_url: create_url)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**user.rb**

```
before_save :add_more_info

def add_more_info
  self.referrer_url = create_url, 
  self.clout = calc_clout 
end
```

> **note** I don't usually use `self` in model, but somehow this is the only way I could make it work with `before_save` callback